# ImportError: cannot import name 'aiplatform' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, artificial-intelligence, importerror

I was wondering where that error comes from. The package has to be installed additionally to `google.cloud`

Answer (score 10):

Not that straightforward, just do `pip install google-cloud-aiplatform`